# android back buttons, only one piece of code

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I want to write some code that performs the action to go back to the previous activity. Of course I can write a code for each back button that I have, but I would prefer to have only a piece of code working for all the back buttons (and then, for example, to assign the function to the "onclick" event). How can I manage that?

Answer (score 0):

Please use onclick method and that method redirect to previous activity.

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        // your code.
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)

    {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
    {
            // your code
            return true;
        }

       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: @tbz that's what I was thinking, but how to address the previous activity in general (for each button)? and where to put the java function?

Comment: @Helios83 please write with common function for all buttons

Comment: @ TBZ in which .java should I put this function? what is the variable keyCode?

Comment: @TBZ should I add onKeyDown to each class? I guess if I just want to go back, I don't need to overwrite the onBackPressed() method. But if I understand properly, I need to define it inside each class and then call the super method

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance

YourActivity.java

```
public class YouActivity extends BaseActivity {
    Button back_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        back_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        back_button.setOnClickListener(base_listener);
    }
}
```

BaseActivity.java

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    View.OnClickListener base_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //you back action here;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is my back action? how to define it? if I understand I should put onBackPressed() function

Comment: what is the behavior do you want? if you want to close the activity use `finish();` depends on your needs

Comment: I want to call the previous activity. so does such an activity have a general name? isn't it onBackPressed() the function that I need?

Comment: if you want to go back and close the current activity you can use `finish();`, yes you can use `onBackPressed();` you can all it anywhere on the activity

Comment: but if you have a back button UI you can use my code by just using the `base_listener`

Comment: strange if I overwrite the onBackPressed with finish(), the systems signals that the activity has stopped. then it goes back to the previous activity. but I would like to avoid message errors.

Comment: `onBackPressed` is called by back button hardware but you can call it (but not a good practice), but `finish()` can be use to any scenario

Comment: if I define such activity     public void back() {
        finish();

    } and then call "back" on the "onclick", I still have the signal error